Unable to sign in to Docker Desktop and Docker website: Authentication error
I’m unable to sign in to both Docker Desktop and the Docker website. Whenever I try, I get the following error message:
There was an error authenticating your account. Try again.

Steps I have tried so far:
1.  Tried using multiple accounts:
•   All accounts work on other services but fail on Docker Desktop and the Docker website.
2.  Checked my internet connection and firewall settings:
•   Verified there are no blocks on Docker services.
3.  Cleared the Docker Desktop cache and reinstalled the application.
4.  Tried accessing the Docker website on different browsers (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, Edge), but the same error persists.


